# How to parse a List or 2D array since IEnumerable<T> doesn't work?

Tags: c#

Sorry for the confusing question but i really don't know how to pose it better.
Maybe some code is better to visualize my problem.

### What I had at the beginning

```
private void drawFields(Image img, List<Field> Fields , bool clear)
    {            
        Graphics grx = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
        if(clear)
            grx.Clear(Color.White);
        foreach(Field f in Fields)
        {
            grx.DrawImage(img, f.x * Field.width, f.y * Field.height);
        }
    }
```

In this case I am using a List. But I also have a 2 dimensional array (not jagged) of type Field. I don't want to duplicate my code and write the same function with the 2d array instead of the list. Also I don't want to convert the 2d array to a list since it is unnecessarily using cpu ressources.

### I thought replacing the List with IEnumerable would be the solution

```
private void drawFields(Image img, IEnumerable<Field> Fields , bool clear)
    {            
        Graphics grx = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
        if(clear)
            grx.Clear(Color.White);
        foreach(Field f in Fields)
        {
            grx.DrawImage(img, f.x * Field.width, f.y * Field.height);
        }
    }
```

If it was a "normal" array it would work. But 2D arrays do not implement `IEnumerable<T>`
so the following call will give me an error (where Field.allFields is the 2D array)

```
drawFields(Field_n, Field.allFields, true);
```

### The actual question

Is there something else than IEnumerable to fix this problem?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you, but to me it appears like you're trying to treat the 2D array as if it only had a single dimension.

Comment: No I just want to apply the same function on the 2D array. The foreach loop works perfectly. But then I'd have 2 functions with the same body and only the header is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `IEnumerable` and cast it manually. 2D-Arrays do not implement the generic version.

```
IEnumerable<Field> fields = ((IEnumerable)myArray).Cast<Field>();
```

Comment: I thought the cast is using a lot of cpu in comparison to a simple self done conversion.

Comment: @lorenz "thought" or "assumed"? Have you measured it?

Comment: I read a post by john skeet where he used cast and it was by far the slowest. But it can be that it doesn't aplly to this case. It works thank you. I ll stick to it for now. Was missing a using directive

Comment: The main issue with casting is you'll get an unboxing for each element, and unboxing can be slow.

Answer (score 2):

A second approach is to write your own enumerator class to do the conversion from an array to a simple enumerable.

**Disclaimer**: I have not tested this code to check that it works in your case, but it should serve to illustrate the principle.

```
class FieldEnumerator : IEnumerable<Field>
{
    Field[,] array;
    public FieldEnumerator(Field[,] array)
    {
        this.array = array;
    }
    public IEnumerator<Field> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.array.GetLength(0); ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < this.array.GetLength(1); ++j)
            {
                yield return this.array[i, j];
            }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your calling code, you would change

```
drawFields(Field_n, Field.allFields, true);
```

to

```
drawFields(Field_n, new FieldEnumerator(Field.allFields), true);
```

and then your method

```
private void drawFields(Image img, IEnumerable<Field> Fields, bool clear)
```

remains unchanged.

Comment: This looks very nice since I haven't done anything with IEnumerator till now. Thx

Comment: Since you're using yield anyway, can't you get rid of the class and just have the GetEnumerator() method, passing the array into it?

Answer (score 1):

You could go long-hand and write the iteration yourself, in the traditional manner:

In the calling function, declare like this:

```
Field[,] Fields = new Field[4,5];
```

Change the method signature to this:

```
public static void drawFields(Image img, Field[,] fields, bool clear)
```

Then code the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fields.GetLength(0); ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < fields.GetLength(1); ++j)
    {
        Field f = fields[i, j];
        grx.DrawImage(img, f.x * Field.width, f.y * Field.height);
    }
```

Comment: Why shouldn't I stay with the foreach loop since it is working? I think u misunderstood me. I want to change the header so that it accepts 2D arrays as well as Lists.

Comment: Your question is predicated upon it *not* working though, at least, not for a 2D array.

Comment: @lorenzalbert You basically have two realistic choices here. Go with ClickRick's answer and not require a cast, or go with addy2012's answer, perform a cast, and get to keep your method body.

Comment: What isn't working is the header. The body is fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IEnumerable` and cast within the for loop.

```
private void drawFields(Image img, IEnumerable Fields , bool clear)
{            
    Graphics grx = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
    if(clear)
        grx.Clear(Color.White);
    foreach(object o in Fields)
    {
        var f = (Field)o;
        grx.DrawImage(img, f.x * Field.width, f.y * Field.height);
    }
}
```